# How to initialize state in React

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have created a simple State with increasing numbers.
I want to initialize the State when the parameter of the URL is changed, but when I try to do it this way, the Render runs first and the State is not initialized.
I checked the console.log and found that even if I do setState in useEffect, the value is not changed.
Please tell me how to initialize the state in gastby.

Example

```
https://example.com?name=john => https://example.com?name=kid
```

```
import { useLocation } from "@reach/router";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";


const AreaInfoPannel = ({ className, documentList }) => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    setPage(1);
  }, [location.href]);

  const contentsLength = documentList.length;

  const increment = () => {
    contentsLength <= page ? setPage(1) : setPage(page + 1);
  };
  const decrement = () => {
    page <= 1 ? setPage(contentsLength) : setPage(page - 1);
  };
  return (
    <div className={className}>
      <button on_click={decrement}>down</button>
      <button on_click={increment}>up</button>
      <div>{page}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AreaInfoPannel;
```

The line "useLocation" acquires the URL information, "useEffect" detects the URL change, and "setState" initializes the value .

Comment: Is it not possible to initialize the functional component in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

```js
 const [page, setPage] = useState(1); // this is initializing the state
 useEffect(() => {
    setPage(1);// this is updating the state
  }, [location.href]);
```

So everytime you visit a url which renders this component the state is **initialized** not **updated**

Comment: I hope you are right, but the current problem is that if you change the parameters dynamically, they are rendered before they are initialized.